# I enjoyed not only what

Tags: grammaticality

> Great post. I enjoyed not only what said about how that word should be written, but, especially, how all the matter has been treated.

I would like to know if the sentence above is correct.

Just a little bit of context: I really appreciated an article about English grammar, then I would like to compliment author on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking:

> Great post.

is not a full sentence. It's shorthand for:

> This is a great post.

That said, this structure gets used all the time in conversation:

> Let's go bowling tonight.
>   **Great idea.**

It also gets used in print, when the author feels like the stripped down sentence might have more impact.

So, asking about "correctness" can be tricky sometimes.

As for:

> I enjoyed not only what said about how that word should be written, but, especially, how all the matter has been treated.

Aside from the missing "you" (between "what" and "said"), I can't find anything else grammatically or syntactically incorrect, but it still reads a little awkwardly. I would suggest:

> I enjoyed what you said about how that word should be written, but I appreciated how you explained the entire matter even more.

There's nothing *wrong* with using *not only* – it's a valid construct – I just felt it read awkwardly in your sentence. If you really wanted to use it, I'd move it to the front:

> Not only did I enjoy what you said about how that word should be written, but I especially enjoyed how all the other matter was treated as well.

But that's a matter of *style*, not *correctness*.

Comment: As a side note, I'd recommend waiting a half day or so before accepting an answer. Accepting the first answer that comes along sometimes discourages other folks from giving their opinions on the matter. (I've even seen some occasions where a user accepted an answer that had erroneous information!)

Comment: Ok J.R. Thank you. By the way, the native-like version of a sentence of mine is always welcome, of course.

Comment: The problem is, rewriting sentences is considered "proofreading," which is considered off-topic for this site (because we don't want this Stack Exchange site to devolve into a free editing service). I felt it was okay to bend the rules a little bit in this case, though, because I thought it was worth discussing how a sentence might be "correct" yet read awkwardly, and another sentence might be "incorrect" but come across just fine - that might ultimately be a positive contribution to the ELL archives.

Comment: I wish I were an English writer who was looking for only a free editing service! :-) Anyway, I agree with you.